# How do I call stored proc in DB2 using raw SQL (LINQPad)

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, output-parameter

I have a stored procedure called `MY_STORED_PROC`.  It has an integer input parameter and an integer output parameter.

I've tried all manner of `DECLARE`s, `BEGIN`s and `END`s and `call`s, and I've started to look into changing statement terminators (??), and I can't for the life of me get it to work in raw SQL (LINQPad in my case).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11529261/614523) gives

```sql
DECLARE outParam NUMBER;
BEGIN
    TP.MY_STORED_PROC(26431414, outParam);
END;
```

which returns

> ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/SUN64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "DECLARE OUTPARAM NUMBER@ 
>   BEGIN" was found following "
>   ".  Expected tokens may include:  "`<values>`".

I have also tried setting the terminator/delimeter:

```
--#SET DELIMITER @
DECLARE outParam NUMBER@
BEGIN
    TP.MY_STORED_PROC(26431414, outParam);
END@

--#SET TERMINATOR @
DECLARE outParam NUMBER@
BEGIN
    TP.MY_STORED_PROC(26431414, outParam);
END@
```

both return

> ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/SUN64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "DECLARE OUTPARAM NUMBER@ 
>   BEGIN" was found following "
>   ".  Expected tokens may include:  "`<values>`".

`call` gives the same thing.

Calling it via `OdbcCommand` works fine with `call`:

```cs
var input = 789;
var sql = "call TP.MY_STORED_PROC (?, ?);";

using (var tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
using (var command = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@input_param", OdbcType.Int, 32).Value = input;
    command.Parameters.Add("@output_param", OdbcType.Int, 32).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    object output = command.Parameters["@output_param"].Value;
    if (output is DBNull)
        return null;

    int output = Convert.ToInt32(output);
    return output;
}
```

How can I call this thing and get a meaningful result in the output parameter, which I then stuff in a result set and echo to the screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to call the stored procedure from the DB2 Command Line Processor, you don't need to do anything fancy.  Just use a parameter marker for any output parameters:

```
$ db2 "call tp.my_stored_proc(26431414, ?)"
```

The DB2 CLP will just print the name / value of each output parameter.

For example, the built-in `GET_DBSIZE_INFO` stored procedure has 3 output parameters.  You call it like this:

```
$ db2 "call get_dbsize_info(?, ?, ?, -1)"

  Value of output parameters
  --------------------------
  Parameter Name  : SNAPSHOTTIMESTAMP
  Parameter Value : 2013-05-06-23.49.14.581776

  Parameter Name  : DATABASESIZE
  Parameter Value : 253607936

  Parameter Name  : DATABASECAPACITY
  Parameter Value : 2179940352

  Return Status = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Not quite what I'm after.  My question is more "how would I run this stored procedure `get_dbsize_info(?, ?, ?, -1)` in an SQL script, similar to the way I can run `ALTER TABLE TESTUSER.EMPLOYEE ADD NEW_COL VARCHAR(25)`?"  Think database upgrade scripts (through RoundhousE or similar).

Comment: I am not familiar with how Roundhouse executes the SQL statements - i.e. does it connect directly to the database to execute statements, or does it just execute scripts using each DBMS’ command line utility?  If the latter, you put `call get_dbsize_info(?,?,?,-1);` into a file (say, `x.sql`) and execute it with the DB2 CLP:   `db2 -tvf x.sql`.

Comment: Thanks for your continued interest.  I would like to execute these scripts directly against the database.